# How to get the enumeration's name instead of the case's name in swift?

Tags: swift, syntax

Now I need a convenient way to get the name of enumeration itself ? Here is an example.

```
enum SimpleEnum {
    case firstCase
    case secondCase
    case thirdCase
}
let simpleEnum: SimpleEnum = .firstCase
print("\(simpleEnum)") // return the "firstCase", but I want "SimpleEnum"
```

I know the following code would work.

```
enum SimpleEnum: CustomStringConvertible {
    case firstCase
    case secondCase
    case thirdCase

    var description: String { return "SimpleEnum" }
}
let simpleEnum: SimpleEnum = .firstCase
print("\(simpleEnum)") // Ok, it return "SimpleEnum"
```

However, I just want an universal way instead of typing "SimpleEnum" for each enum.

Comment: `type(of: simpleEnum)`

Comment: That is. I did not know about the existence of type(of:) since it is a operator and xcode would not hint me. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the type object from an enum case by calling `type(of:)`. You can then convert that to a string by calling `String.init(describing:)`:

```
let simpleEnum: SimpleEnum = .firstCase
let enumName = String(describing: type(of: simpleEnum))
```

If you want to get the type name from a type instead, you can do this:

```
let enumName = String(describing: SimpleEnum.self)
```

Comment: `type(of:)` just what I want.